# Json object to key value pairs

Tags: javascript

I want to convert

```
var connection = {
   someName:'someValue'
}
```

to

```
data:{'connection.someName':'someValue'}
```

how can i do that?

To elaborate more;

I have

```
var data ={connection : {name : 'SomeName', url:'SomeUrl'}}
```

and i post

```
$.ajax({
  type : 'POST'
  data : data
  ....
})
```

and my back-end expects form data like

```
connection.name='SomeName'
connection.url='SomeUrl'
```

so  it can bind connection data to Connection bean

Thanks.

Comment: Why would you want to have the `data.` in your key? And what is that result, a JSON-like string?

Comment: Actually my back-end expects form data like lets say not data but
connection.name='someName', 'connection.url'='someUrl'
so it can bind request input to connection bean. Btw i am trying post data with JQuery and on the backend i am using Jodd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst the result you are looking for is technically valid JSON, this will not parse as expected:

```
var x = JSON.parse("{\"data.someName\":\"someValue\"}");
x.data.someName;
// Error: x.data is undefined
```

This is because the parser treats the entire literal as a single key, so you would have to access the value like so:

```
var x = JSON.parse("{\"data.someName\":\"someValue\"}");
x["data.someName"]
// "someValue"
```

What you actually want in order to be compliant, parsable JSON is this:

```
{"data":{"someName":"someValue"}}
```

The parser will treat this appropriately:

```
var x = JSON.parse("{\"data\":{\"someName\":\"someValue\"}}");
x.data.someName;
// "someValue";
```